# Prevent Element from Resizing on Page Scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and I have a div element that I want to keep the same size and position no matter what. When a user goes to a web page and clicks (Ctr+Shift+(+ or -)) I want the element to keep its same size and position. Is this possible with javascript, CSS, and HTML. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, by defining the `width` and `height` of an element with a fixed value, like `100px`, then the browser won't affect the size.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier That is exact what it does though. I have definitive px and the web page scales those values that's whats happening

Comment: Create a runnable snippet in which we can experience your issue and add it to your question.

Comment: I added a solution that could help but without some code is a little difficult to guess

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved by viewport units. Example:

```css
div{
  width:40vw;
  height:40vh;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

viewport units.
Example:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we cannot see your code or part of it so we can only guess what you really need. But if I guess right then the following code will help you achieve what you want

Set width using VW and height using VH, that will help you make the width and height be always the same no matter what.

1 VH or VW means 1% of the device screen width or height. So if you set the following values:

```
.nomattetwhat {
//this will fix the width to 69% of the screen size

width:69vw;min-width:69vw;

// this the height
height:69vh;min-height:69vh;

// if you want the windows to be a popup or modal or always over the rest of the others use
z-index:99;

// if you want to adjust the position to be sticky

position:sticky;

// if you want to move it around and on top

position:absolute;

// lastly if you want it to be in the middle of everything, vertically and horizontally centered, just use

display:block;margin:0 auto;

}
```

I hope this help you in what you need. You can always ask me something here